# How to cut everything after a specific character, but in case string doesn't contain it do nothing?

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say i have following data:

```
fjflka, kdjf
ssssllkjf fkdsjl
skfjjsld, kjl
jdkfjlj, ksd
lkjlkj hjk
```

I want to cut out everything after ',' but in case the string doesn't contain this character, it wont do anything, if i use substr and cut everything after ',' the string which doesn't contain this character shows as null. How do i achieve this? Im using oracle 11g.

Comment: "Cut our everything after " - Do you need  `fjflka` or `kdjf` in your output?

Comment: "fjflka" the first part, before ','

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your table :

```
SQL> desc mytable
     s varchar2(100)
```

you may use:

```
select decode(instr(s,','),0,s,substr(s,1,instr(s,',')-1)) from mytable;
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/980e4/1)

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Simply use **regexp_substr**

```
with t_view as (
select 'fjflka, kdjf' as text from dual union
select 'ssssllkjf fkdsjl' from dual union
select 'skfjjsld, kjl' from dual union
select 'jdkfjlj, ksd' from dual union
select 'lkjlkj hjk' from dual
)

select text,regexp_substr(text,'[^,]+',1,1) from t_view;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the below query works as per your requirement.

```
with mytable as 
(select 'aaasfasf wqwe' s from dual 
union all 
select 'aaasfasf, wqwe' s from dual)
select s,substr(s||',',1,instr(s||',',',')-1) from mytable;
```